# How do I prevent Blender from randomly duplicating items?

Tags: edit-mode

I am really enjoying the Blender program, but I am also having some extreme issues with it as well. It seems to "glitch out" randomly, and when I try to replicate the scenario, sometimes it will do it again, other times it will work correctly, and other times, it messes up completely differently! For instance, in the file that I attached, I am trying to create a "Firebending" effect. I have the smoke flow and domain set up, but for some reason, Blender keeps randomly duplicating the domain at different points throughout the video. I'm really not sure how else to describe it and get help because the events are so random and so confusing to me. I often follow video tutorials exactly, but if I mess up and have to undo a step, Blender loses its mind it seems. Is anyone willing to try and help me out with some of these problems? Thanks in advance!

Ethan

PS: The video tutorial I am using is [this fire power video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_2ZNf2VDQw) if it helps you guys out with answering my question.

EDIT: Here is the second attempt I had after removing Smoke Adaptive Domain and rotating the sphere 90 degrees. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Modifiers are in wrong order. Move Smoke modifier down in the stack so Particle system would be first. At least i think this is what you are trying to achieve.

Oh and it ain't random duplicating. You have "Smoke adaptive Domain" checked on Domain Smoke properties and because modifiers were in wrong order, it looked like there is duplicated domain as it should normally stay inside the original domain.

EDIT: Well that particle system seemed bit complicated for me to fast figure out how to make that more "firebending" style you wanted. But here is idea for you how to do it easier without using particle system. Added another domain, sphere and wind. might be more better way to do this, but this is what i would use

[image]

Comment: I ended up just removing "Smoke Adaptive Domain" because it kept struggling no matter which order I put the modifiers in. This is the new file. As you can see, I removed SAD, and I rotated the sphere 90 degrees in an attempt to get more of a "fireball" type look. I still didn't get the kind of fire that I wanted. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sdcIu-OntE)

I was going for something more like the link I posted in this comment.